# Keep all records with duplicates and get the lowest id of each duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, duplicates, vba

I would like to create a script that will keep all duplicates and get the lowest id of each duplicate values and populate the ID_TO_KEEP field of all duplicates with it.

What I want to happen:

```
+-----+----------------+-----------+-----------+
| id  | name           |address    |id_to_keep |
+-----+----------------+-----------+-----------+
| 131 | google company |california |131        |
| 223 | google inc.    |california |131        |
| 334 | msn            |boston     |           |
| 442 | facebook       |california |           |
| 543 | yahoo inc.     |washington |543        |
| 621 | yahoo limited  |washington |543        |
+-----+----------------+-----------+-----------+
```

On the example above, "google company" and "google inc." will be considered as duplicate since they are just the same company and then the script must compare their id and get the lowest one then populate the id_to_keep field with the lowest id.

Hope someone can help me with this. Either on Excel Macro or SQL script

Comment: How do we know that they're the same company?

Comment: when address are the same

Comment: can also add postal code, state, province and other relevant address details then if they are the same it is considered as the same company

Comment: OK, according to the info provided, facebook and google are the same company, so this example isn't fairly representative of the problem.

Comment: of course if their names are mostly the same then the next thing you will look for is the address and if they matched. it will be considered as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this... but note that you may need a more robust method for establishing whether or not two companies with the similar names are in fact the same...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,name           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
 ,address    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (131 ,'google company','california'),
 (223 ,'google inc.','california'),
 (334 ,'msn','boston'),
 (442 ,'facebook','california'),
 (543 ,'yahoo inc.','washington'),
 (621 ,'yahoo limited','washington');

 SELECT x.* 
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT MIN(id) min_id FROM my_table GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',1),address ) y
     ON y.min_id = x.id;

 +-----+----------------+------------+
 | id  | name           | address    |
 +-----+----------------+------------+
 | 442 | facebook       | california |
 | 131 | google company | california |
 | 334 | msn            | boston     |
 | 543 | yahoo inc.     | washington |
 +-----+----------------+------------+
```

It's trivial to rewrite this as a DELETE...

```
 DELETE x
   FROM my_table x
   LEFT 
   JOIN
      ( SELECT MIN(id) min_id FROM my_table GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',1),address ) y
     ON y.min_id = x.id
  WHERE y.min_id IS NULL;

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +-----+----------------+------------+
 | id  | name           | address    |
 +-----+----------------+------------+
 | 131 | google company | california |
 | 334 | msn            | boston     |
 | 442 | facebook       | california |
 | 543 | yahoo inc.     | washington |
 +-----+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. but what I need is to keep all those with duplicates then delete those records that doesn't have duplicate and the most important is to populate the ID_TO_KEEP column with the lowest ID

Comment: That seems like the the least important part - see edit!

Comment: how to use substring_index in sqlserver2008?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use variables (I assumed the table is named test_test) :

```
       SELECT
            id,
            @last_id := IF(@lastGroupID!=SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_test.name,' ',1),test_test.id,@last_id) as id_to_keep,
            @lastGroupID := SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_test.name,' ',1)  as company,
            address
        FROM bigwf.test_test, (select @lastGroupID:=null) as lastGroupID,(select @last_id:= (select min(id) from test_test)) as lastID
        order by id
```

=> This will give you

```
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
| id  | id_to_keep | company  | address    |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
| 131 |        131 | google   | california |
| 223 |        131 | google   | california |
| 334 |        334 | msn      | boston     |
| 442 |        442 | facebook | california |
| 543 |        543 | yahoo    | washington |
| 621 |        543 | yahoo    | washington |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
```

edit : the fake table (select @i:=0) as rownum_table is not necessary.

Comment: can u explain to me whats the use of @?

Comment: @ means @last_id is a variable. In the select part, := means I assigned the value on the right part (which is the result of an if statement). For each rows returned, the value of theses variable may change or not, depending on the right statement. This is a workaround for the lack of MySQL concerning windowed query (as it exists in Oracle, SQLServer and others...)

Comment: I cant use Substring_Index function. I'm just using a 2008 version of SQL. is there alternative with that?

Comment: I guess you were working on MySQL as your tags said... I can't help with Microsoft SQL Server. Consider using MySQL :)